# Polar-cartesian conversion

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Need some help here:

Transform the polar equation to rectangular coordinates and identify the curve represented by
$$r = \sin t + \cos t$$

What I've done:

$$r^2 = r\sin t+r\cos t $$

$$x^2+y^2 = x + y$$

---

I'm kind of clueless on how to go from there though. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

$$x^2+y^2 = x + y \iff x^2 - x + y^2 - y =0 $$

Complete the squares, and you'll find you have a circle!

$$\left(x^2 - x + \frac 14\right) + \left(y^2 - y + \frac 14\right) = \frac 12$$

$$\left(x - \frac 12\right)^2 + \left(y - \frac 12\right)^2 = \left(\sqrt{\frac 12}\right)^2$$

It's a circle centered at $\left(\frac 12, \frac 12\right)$ of radius $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$

Comment: Thanks! but how can you see that it's going to be 1/2 from x^2 - x + y^2 - y ?

Comment: We add $\frac 14 + \frac 14 =\frac 12$ to each side: in order to [complete the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square)